# Getting position after using CCScaleBy

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm scaling my sprite in cocos2d. While using the method CCScaleBy, it's scaling the sprite but I can not get the position at which it's scaling. If i use CCMoveBy I can get the position.

Can anyone help me with it??

Thank you,

Anks

Answer (score 0):

CCMoveBy alters the position of the sprite. CCScaleBy alters the scale property but not the position.
The translation (position) and scale transformation is done around the anchorPoint.

You could calculate the resulting coordinates of the sprite using the position, scale, rotation and anchorPoint.

Comment: Ok, can you please tell me how to do it??

Comment: Actually I want position at every nano second, is that possible? Or will i just get resulting point?? Let me know.

Comment: What @phix23 said is that the position does not change from the use of CCScaleBy.  If you want the position, it will be exactly the same as it was a nano second before, unless you are moving it by some other means at the same time.